# Google cloud storage upload not working with C# API

Tags: c#, google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to upload a simple image to Google cloud storage via the C# API. It seems to succeed but I don't see anything in my Google cloud bucket.

The code I have so far:

```
Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer init = new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer();
init.ApiKey = "@@myapikey@@";
init.ApplicationName = "@@myapplicationname@@";

Google.Apis.Storage.v1.StorageService ss = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1.StorageService(init);

var fileobj = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object()
{
    Bucket = "images",
                    Name = "some-file-" + new Random().Next(1, 666)
};

Stream stream = null;
stream = new MemoryStream(img);

Google.Apis.Storage.v1.ObjectsResource.InsertMediaUpload insmedia;
insmedia = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1.ObjectsResource.InsertMediaUpload(ss, fileobj, "images", stream, "image/jpeg");
insmedia.Upload();
response.message = img.Length.ToString();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anyone looking to do this I'm going to help you out since I don't want you to spend a day scratching your heads so here is how you do this.

First of all create a "Service Account" type credentials which will give you a private key with p12 extension save this somewhere you can reference on your server.

Now do this:

```
String serviceAccountEmail = "YOUR SERVICE EMAIL HERE";

var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"PATH TO YOUR p12 FILE HERE", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
    {
        Scopes = new[] { Google.Apis.Storage.v1.StorageService.Scope.DevstorageFullControl }
    }.FromCertificate(certificate));

Google.Apis.Storage.v1.StorageService ss = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1.StorageService(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "YOUR APPLICATION NAME HERE",
});

var fileobj = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object()
{
    Bucket = "YOUR BUCKET NAME HERE",
    Name = "file"
};

Stream stream = null;
stream = new MemoryStream(img);

Google.Apis.Storage.v1.ObjectsResource.InsertMediaUpload insmedia;
insmedia = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1.ObjectsResource.InsertMediaUpload(ss, fileobj, "YOUR BUCKET NAME HERE", stream, "image/jpeg");
insmedia.Upload();
```

Comment: Creating Service Account is in your developer console under Api & Auth -> Credentials