# C# after uploading image, get url of uploaded image in google cloud storage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, google-cloud-storage, google-api-dotnet-client

I created an image uploader using c# mvc5. I managed to upload the images to google cloud storage. **Now I want to get the url of the uploaded file to return to the user for reference**. I've been looking around the docs in google and can't find it. Anyone can provide me some links or codes will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using AppEngine? Which API?

Comment: I'm using Google API Storage and Google API Service I got from NuGet. Sorry not really familiar with the APIs of Google.

Comment: I'm not sure, When I checked it is google api dotnet client. This is where I based my working codes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27074196/google-cloud-storage-upload-not-working-with-c-sharp-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation page on [Request URIs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference-uris).

In general, if you upload to a bucket named `foo` and an object named `bar/baz`, the URL for your object will be:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/foo/bar/baz
```

With the [GCS C# .NET library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/storage/v1), you can use one of the [Storage.v1.Data.Object](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/storage/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Storage_1_1v1_1_1Data_1_1Object.html) class properties:

- [MediaLink](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/storage/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Storage_1_1v1_1_1Data_1_1Object.html#a6ad054015c1b72ade806ab374e300893) to get the download link, or
- [SelfLink](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/storage/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Storage_1_1v1_1_1Data_1_1Object.html#a336fda231d16070e1edb31ea7f47d137) to get the canonical URL for the object.

Comment: Can I get this url programmatically?

Comment: I was expecting it to be the same url from your first answer, but this will do. Thanks.

Comment: The difference is the XML API vs JSON API.